# Page reloading for every "it" statement in protractor and printing "."

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Have anyone found fix for this. I am new to protractor and got some script running. I have a login page and once logged in search for a user. My spec.js has the following structure.

```
describe('Smoke', function() {
//sum stuff
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get('https://login/');
  });

  it('should have a title', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('title');
    browser.pause()
  });

  it('and Login to MSIX', function () {
    login.login(username);

 });

 it('search for a user', function () {
  searchUser.searchForUser();
 });

 it ('print test result', function () {
  var userN = loginName.getText().then((text) => {
    return text;
   })
//  at this point data is still a managed promise!
 userN.then((text) => {
   console.log("Logged in user is: "+text);
   console.log("User " +username+" logged in successfully"); // your text would be printed!
  })
})
});
```

For every "it" statement the page reloads and I am losing the content on the page. Also if you notice the last "it" statement to print test result I am noticing "." before the output in console

```
**..**[12:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("query.identifier") - the first result will be used
**.**Logged in user is: sample user
User abc logged in successfully
**.**
```

Comment: Why do you have `login.login()` and  `searchUser.searchForUser()` in their own it blocks? These are steps you need to take to setup your tests. Put them in the `beforeAll` or `beforeEach`. For the code you've presented you really only need two `it` blocks. The one for title and one for loginName. Also you can simplify that last bit by removing the userN variable and just doing `loginName.getText().then((text) => { //log all the things... });`

Comment: Hey @tehbeardedone, sorry for not giving complete visibility of my code. The login and SearchUser are from separate JS files. I did not included the require code here. Also thanks for the syntax for console part. I have updated as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling it to reload the page for every `it` by using `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get('https://login/');
});
```

Use `beforeAll` instead:

```
beforeAll(function () {
  browser.get('https://login/');
});
```

Comment: That was awesome, thanks for the help @Pop-A-Stash. I am still noticing the "." at the console. Is anything I need to modify

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Different test runners have different ways of displaying the test run progress. That could be what the dots are. My test runner draws a nyan cat to display the progress :)